# different result from model_fit.plot_predict() and model_fit.predict() from arima

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, predict, arima

I want to know how arima works well by using difference between predict value and real value. So I used predict()(the below one) but it is different from the value of plot_predict()(above one). (please look how it is different) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bftpu.png) I think plot_predict values are what I want, since it is closer to the real values but what I can get from predict() is so low. Please help me to find the answer. Appreciate for your help.

For the first one, I used

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

model = ARIMA(sales, order=(0,1,1))
model_fit = model.fit(trend='nc',full_output=True, disp=1)
print(model_fit.summary())
model_fit.plot_predict(dynamic=False)
```

for the below one, I used

```
predict=model_fit.predict()
plt.plot(predict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of `statsmodels` do you use?

I think you are using `statsmodels` version 10.2 (which is currently a default version of `statsmodels` in Google Colab)

Pay attention to the `typ` parameter in the function ([described in this link](https://www.statsmodels.org/v0.10.2/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMAResults.predict.html)) and change the value into `levels` to get the prediction value instead of differenced value.

```py
predict=model_fit.predict(typ='levels')
plt.plot(predict)
plt.plot(sales)
```